# Adobe Javascript If/Else error with dropdown list

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I am trying to have a second field automatically populate with a numerical code assigned to an option within a dropdown list that it references. I currently have this code on a mouse up action, but it never changes from the first event value.

Any help is appreciated.

```
// Custom calculation script for text field
(function () {
    var v = getField("Dropdown1").valueAsString;
    // Set this field's value based on the input

    if (v = "Option 1") {
        event.value == "41998";
        return;
    } else if (v = "Option 3") {
        event.value == "42005";
        return;
    } else if (v = "Option 3") {
        event.value == "23469";
        return;
    } else {
        event.value == "23469";
        return;
    }

    // If none of the above fit, blank this field
    event.value == "";
})();
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle with an example of your code including the html that is being affected? It may have to do with how you are binding the custom calculation script to the change event, so it would be helpful to see that piece of your work

Comment: @wolffer-east This isn't browser JS, it's an Adobe script

Comment: My mistake, I missed the tag, apologies

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up the `comparison ==` and the `assignment =` operators.

Your code should read like:

```
(function () {
    var v = getField("Dropdown1").valueAsString;
    // Set this field's value based on the input

    if (v === "Option 1") {
        event.value = "41998";
        return;
    } else if (v === "Option 3") {
        event.value = "42005";
        return;
    } else if (v === "Option 3") {
        event.value = "23469";
        return;
    } else {
        event.value = "23469";
        return;
    }

    // If none of the above fit, blank this field
    event.value = "";
})();
```

See these two links for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment_operators

Comment: Perfect thank you! Definitely a learning experience with overlooking some basics.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit late, but if the values associated to the selections in the combobox/listbox are unique for all options, you can do it without any if…else evaluation.

In this case, you set the return value of the option in the combobox/listbox to that value. In your field where you display that value you add this simple line of JavaScript:

```
event.value = this.getField("Dropdown1").valueAsString ;
```

And that does it.

Now, to get the blank field value, you set the return value of the option set as default value in the combobox/listbox to " ".

If for any reason this approach is not usable, using the switch() statement would IMHO be more suitable for this scenario; the function body would look like this:

```
switch(this.getField("DropDown1").valueAsString) {
case "Option 1":
event.value = "41998";
break ;
case "Option 2":
event.value = "42005";
break ;
case "Option 3":
event.value = "23469";
break ;
default:
event.value = "" ;
}
```

And that would also give the desired result.